# VBA Excel 2010: Help using Application.Run within worksheet scope

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to call any arbitrary function using *Application.Run* within a worksheet macro in Excel2010. In the following code located in "Sheet1", why does z2 return the right answer and z3 return an Empty variant?

```
Option Explicit

Function myfun11(x) As Double
    myfun11 = x + 10
    Debug.Print "I WORK!"
End Function

Sub test1230()
    Dim x, output1, output2
    Dim str1

    x = 1
    str1 = "Sheet1.myfun11"

    output1 = Sheet1.myfun11(x)
    output2 = Application.Run(str1, x)
End Sub
```

In the code snippet, Debug.print is called twice, meaning that Application.Run successfully runs the function. However, it fails to retrieve **output2** (but successfully gets output1). I tested the code again in a "Module" scope like this (Code is inside the module "Module1") and Application.Run successfully retrieves both output1 and output2:

```
Option Explicit

Function myfun11(x) As Double
    myfun11 = x + 10
    Debug.Print "I WORK!"
End Function

Sub test1230()
    Dim x, output1, output2
    Dim str1

    x = 1
    str1 = "Module1.myfun11"

    output1 = Module1.myfun11(x)
    output2 = Application.Run(str1, x)
End Sub
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening? Is this a VB bug or is there a reason for this problem? Also does anybody have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Interesting question. I get the same results as you do. Generally I do not put any public/callable functions in a Worksheet module, I use the object modules only for the event-handlers pertaining to those objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling excel worksheet function from excel cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391229/calling-excel-worksheet-function-from-excel-cell).  **FYI** Spolsky, who answered that question, basically is the guy who *designed* Visual Basic for Applications.  He knows what he's talking about :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found a workaround. I don't know why this works (or more importantly, why Application.Run doesn't work) but it does. It seems like Application.Run doesn't seem to work particularly well sometimes.

Instead, I can use:

```
output3 = CallByName(Sheet1, "myfun11", VbMethod, x)
```